# Проверка роли в Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Пытаюсь разграничить доступ к страницам. [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57437070/how-to-create-a-middleware-for-check-role-in-nuxtjs) увидел пример, nuxt-auth уже стоял, создал файл в middleware, код:

```
export default function ({ $auth, redirect }) {
   if (!$auth.hasScope('admin')) {
     redirect('/404')
   }
}
```

Но никакого эффекта нет

Comment: попробуйте `return redirect('/path')`

Comment: Всё так же, если из условия убрать !, то перебрасывает. Возможно я не правильно понял суть hasScope? Я пробовал передавать данные о пользователе как role: 'admin', так и scope: 'admin'

Comment: Согласно последней документации, `roles` должно быть массивом или объектом

Comment: {"id":5,"scope":"admin","name":"","email":"124@mail.ru"} - вот кусок из массива

Comment: `"scope":["admin"]` сделайте и при условии настроек по умолчанию модуль должен сработать с middleware, приведенным выше

Comment: Не подскажете, как на laravel отправить? Я сделал тип данных enum у столбца scope